# An isosceles right triangle has legs of length 10. A pin is dropped into it and lands somewhere in the triangle where all places are equally likely.

Tags: probability, geometry, statistics

What is the probability that it does not land within 2 units of any of the sides?

From my calculations, I get that the smaller triangle has side lengths of 4,4, 4 root 2

(-2 at the right angle and -4 at the 45 degree angles -> 10 - 6 = 4)

If that were true, the answer would be 8/50 or .16.

However, the answer key says ~.101

I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: If the answer is to be independent of the angle formed by the legs, it has to be zero, since there are clearly (sufficiently acute or sufficiently obtuse) isosceles triangles in which the answer is zero.

Comment: It must depend on the angle.  As you say, it is 0 if you take the third side near 0 (or near 20).  But for an equilateral triangle there is certainly a positive probability.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write isosceles *right* triangle

Comment: Fair enough.  The general question is interesting though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from translating the hypotenuse.  Let's be explicit about it.  Suppose your original triangle is made by intersecting the lines y = 0, x = 0, and y = -x + 10.  Two of those lines are easy to translate, so the "good" triangle has borders along y = 2 and x = 2.  the hypotenuse is more subtle.  The translated hypotenuse has slope -1 and passes through the translate of (0, 10), say.  But every point on the hypotenuse is to move by a vector -($\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{2}$) as this is perpendicular to the hypotenuse and has length 2.  Thus the translated hypotenuse goes through (-$\sqrt{2}$, 10 - $\sqrt{2}$).  As it has slope -1 we quickly see that the translated hypotenuse has the equation $$y = -x + 10 - 2 \sqrt{2}$$
A little algebra now shows that the good triangle is a right isosceles triangle with legs 6 - 2$\sqrt{2}$ Thus it has area $\frac{1}{2}$ $(6 - 2\sqrt{2})^2$ which is about 5.029 .  As the original triangle had area 50, we get the desired probability by dividing by 50, hence a bit less than .101 .